# Making DataGridViewComboBoxCell control drop down on first click when DataGridView does not have focus

Tags: vb.net, focus, mouseclick-event, datagridviewcomboboxcell

I have seen a lot of questions similar to this but nothing that addresses my issue.  I have a panel in a windows VB.Net application that has a hierarchy of visible controls, one of which is a DataViewGrid control that may contain a DataGridViewComboBoxCell control. The DataViewGrid is a child control of other controls and it does not have initial focus.  What I am wanting is for a user to be able to, with a single mouse click, is to click on the dropdown of a visible DataGridViewComboBoxCell control and to make the dropdown list for it visible. Currently the first mouse click is switching focus to the DataGridView control and a second mouse click is required to show the dropdown list. Is there a way to accomplish this with a single mouse click?  I don't know if this is possible but it would certainly be nice.

Comment: You could try using one of the other events, such as Mouse Enter to give focus.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the EditMode property of DataGridView control to "EditOnEnter".

[image]